# Two column display config.xml

Tags: joomla-3.x, configuration

I am developing a Joomla 3.4 component where I set the component parameters in config.xml. The configuration are shown using 'JToolBarHelper::preferences'.

Is there a way to show the configuration in 2 columns.

Comment: Add bootstrap 2 css classes for cols like span6 might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of such a feature.

Behind the scenes you are actually calling com_config. So it's maybe worth inspecting the code for this component to see if there is such a feature somewhere hidden.